# Shapley values do not add up to prediction

Tags: r, random-forest, shapley-value

I am building a RF model to predict cervical cancer from biopsies ([data](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/cervical.html#cervical)).

I am then trying to explain the predictions using Shapley values. To do this I use the `mli` library in R.

I am facing however two issues:

1. The predicted probabilities from the Random Forest and the Shapley values differ. I guess this can be attributed to MC sampling but it is nevertheless a bit worrying.
2. **the real issue**: when I get the Shapley values for a given prediction, **the sum of the contributions + average class probability does not add up to the final prediction**. This is not supposed to happen from what the package [link](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shapley.html#the-shapley-value-in-detail) states as the Efficiency property of these values.

I have tried to de-transform it assuming that the formula uses a log-odds transformation under the hood, but nothing sensible is coming out.

Any ideas?

Code for reproduction (download the dataset from this [link](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00383/risk_factors_cervical_cancer.csv)):

```
library(iml)
library(randomForest)

testdf <- read.csv('./M2ER/risk_factors_cervical_cancer.csv')

table(testdf$Biopsy)

## subset variables to the ones that should be used in the book
cervical = dplyr::select(testdf, Age, Number.of.sexual.partners, First.sexual.intercourse,
                         Num.of.pregnancies, Smokes, Smokes..years., Hormonal.Contraceptives, Hormonal.Contraceptives..years.,
                         IUD, IUD..years., STDs, STDs..number., STDs..Number.of.diagnosis, STDs..Time.since.first.diagnosis,
                         STDs..Time.since.last.diagnosis, Biopsy)

# NA imputation
imputer = mlr::imputeMode()


cervical_impute = mlr::impute(cervical, classes = list(numeric = mlr::imputeMode()))
cervical = cervical_impute$data


testmod <- randomForest(as.factor(Biopsy)~., data = cervical)

predict(testmod, cervical, type='prob')[1,]

predictor <- Predictor$new(model=testmod, data = cervical %>% select(-Biopsy), 
                           y = as.factor(cervical$Biopsy), 
                           type="prob")
shapley <- Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = (cervical %>% select(-Biopsy))[1, ], sample.size = 100)
shapley$plot()
shapley$y.hat.interest
shapley$y.hat.average
shapley$results %>% filter(class==1) %>% summarise(sum(phi)) #should be equal to the difference between y.hat.interest and y.hat.average
```

Comment: Please show the actual results, rather than the code.

Comment: Two quick ideas to check: 

1) Shapley values are the log odds by default. They are additive in the space of log odds, so the sum of the shapley values has to be done before converting them into probabilities.

2) The intercept has to be added to recover the predictions

Comment: The issue might be that you are getting approximate Shapley values which don't necessarily add up to the difference. `fastshap` has a parameter `adjust = TRUE` to fix this (see discussion here: https://github.com/bgreenwell/fastshap/issues/6). with the `shapper` package they do add up, maybe there's a built-in adjustment.